# Can I access record values or object members in point-free style in F#?

Tags: f#

Take this trivial example:

```fsharp
type Foo = { bar : string }

let bars =
  [ { bar = "abc" }; { bar = "xyz" } ]
    |> List.map (fun x -> x.bar)

// bars is [ "abc"; "xyz" ]
```

Is it possible to avoid writing the lambda using a point-free style? I tried variations on the following to no avail:

```
|> List.map (.bar)
```

The same question goes for object members.

```
open System.IO

let fileNames =
  (DirectoryInfo("c:/x").GetFiles())
    |> Array.map (fun f -> f.FullName)
```

I'd like to shorten it to something like

```
  |> Array.map (.FullName)
```

Comment: Thanks @TheInnerLight, that answers my question!

Comment: There is an F# user voice suggestion for this feature here, by the way: https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/5663326-syntax-for-turning-properties-into-functions